# Stack images as rows in csv file

Tags: python, pandas, image, numpy, csv

I'm trying to save images from a folder as rows of a csv file. Within this csv, each row will correspond to the pixels' values of each image. For that purpose, each image matrix (e.g. (720, 1280, 3)) is flattened and reshaped as row (1, 2764800). In addition, I add the image dimensions (720, 1280) as the first 2 elements of the row. This is because  images with different sizes are handled.

I successfully saved csv file for one image, but I would like to automate the saving process for several images.

This is the code I used for only 1 image

```
import pandas as pd
from PIL import Image 
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.image as img

imageMat = img.imread('images/image1.jpg')
image_reshape = imageMat.flatten().reshape(-1, 1).T

image_csv = [] 
image_csv.append([imageMat.shape[0],imageMat.shape[1]]) 
image_csv = np.array(image_csv) 
image_csv = np.append(image_csv, image_reshape, axis=1) 

mat_df = pd.DataFrame(image_csv)   
mat_df.to_csv('gfgfile.csv', header = None, index = None)
```

Comment: CSV seems like a monumentally poor choice for this. Perhaps put the file name of the actual image in the CSV, and then load it separately into memory from that location?

Comment: You are right @tripleee. Thank you for your comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To automate the code for several images, you can select the image filenames you are going to use. To do that, we can set which images formats we accept and use this information to get the filenames from the folder, as shown below:

```
import os

#Defines image formats supported
image_formats = ['png','jpg','jpeg']
#Gets all filenames that correspond to images
filenames = [f for f in os.listdir('images/') if os.path.isfile('images/'+f) and f.split('.')[-1] in image_formats]
```

In the code above, we listed the names of all the objects inside the folder *images/* and selected those that were filenames and had the supported image extensions.

After we got the filenames, we can loop over them and apply your code, with some modifications, to group all the rows and save them in the dataframe.

```
#List that stores all the images
image_list = []

#Loop over the filenames
for f in filenames:
    #Loads a new image
    imageMat = img.imread('images/'+f)
    #Transforms the image in the flatten array
    image_reshape = imageMat.flatten().reshape(-1, 1).T
    #Saves the image dimensions
    image_csv = [imageMat.shape[0],imageMat.shape[1]]
    #Appends a new row to the list of images, with the dimensions and the flattened image
    image_list.append(image_csv + image_reshape.tolist()[0])

#Creates the dataframe
mat_df = pd.DataFrame(np.array(image_list))
mat_df.to_csv('gfgfile.csv', header = None, index = None)
```